# How can I make an infinite blend in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, blending

I'm trying to make a perfect infinite blend in Illustrator, but I get this.

I started by creating two simple shapes and a closed path, and then blended all of them by the specified distance. Later I cut open a closed path with the scissors tool to connect the two ends together. Is there a way to make the colors seamless?

[image]

Comment: The two end colours would need to be exactly the same.  Couldn't you use a gradient along a stroke for this? It would be easier to just create a gradient with the two end stops the same colour.

Comment: @BillyKerr sorry for not being clear enough on this, I'm trying to create custom shapes, path with stroke is not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blends can have more than two shapes.

So, with that in mind, it's possible to create a blend using 3 or more filled shapes, but make sure the two end ones are the same colour and shape.

For example, here's one with four coloured shapes.  For more complexity, the middle two could even be gradients, or different shapes.

[image]

Then you can bend the path of the blend to any shape you want, making sure the ends overlap.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Maybe you should add that the end shapes must have the same color *and shape*? You could have other shapes along the way.

Comment: @Wolff - yes. I edited it. Thanks

Comment: @BillyKerr I think I understand this now, but is there any way to change the order of the blend, for example I want this to go star-circle-star, instead it goes star-star-circle https://i.imgur.com/tgQHGPk.png

Comment: @Giancarlo I think you would have difficulty lining up two stars at the ends - better to use circles at the ends, since they'll be the same shape, they can overlap perfectly

Comment: @Giancarlo As for the order in which it blends, I think it works in the order they are stacked when you first create them.

Comment: @BillyKerr that solves it, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In this case you might not need to make a blend. Just use a *Gradient* on a stroked circle.

- Select the circle and set the stroke width as desired.
- In the *Gradient panel* set *Type* to *Linear Gradient* and *Stroke* to *Apply gradient along stroke*.
- Setup the gradient so the first and last color stop is the same color.

[image]

Comment: That was the workaround I was thinking of as well. Nice!

Comment: @Wolff Thanks, but I think I formulated my question wrong. I'm trying to achieve this with custom shapes, like this: https://i.imgur.com/vfUpVHy.png

Comment: +1.. I didn't see this and posted something very similar `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Enter the blend's isolation mode by double-clicking it with the move tool. In there, select the starting shape, and copy- paste that. Move it around so it overlaps the original starting shape (you can also use paste in front if you like). Using the layers palette, order the shapes from bottom to top: starting shape - ending shape - copy of ending shape.

Comment: Sorry for the quick and dirty answer, I'm on mobile and not able to add more detail atm. Please refer to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/136490/illustrator-gradual-blends/136500#136500 for a better rundown of the technique.

Comment: I realize now that you might be right about this. The OP's graphics might be more complex than I initially thought. I'm just trying to avoid using blends in general as it introduces a kind of "resolution" to otherwise scalable vector graphics.